# Making a Database Remote

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

I have downloaded MySQL Community Server and I need to make my database remote so that it runs on my professor's computer but I have no idea how to do that. Since I have zero experience with DBs on a PC, please don't hesitate to give me too many details.

Note: What I found on the internet so far didn't work for me. For example some suggest to write this

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

on cmd but I'm getting **ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY 'admin'' at line 1**

Comment: Why don't you ask your professor?

Comment: I would be useful to know things like where your database is (are you trying to run it on a server and connect remotely from your professor's PC to there or running it locally on your professor's PC), what operating system you're installing onto & which version of MySQL you're using.

Comment: Running it locally on my professor's PC, Windows (10) and MySQL 8.0. Thank you for trying to help  @PhilYoung

Comment: How do you connect to your professors PC ?

Comment: I will upload the DB file to the internet, and the professor will download it and test it via scripts. @MaxMuster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full installation instructions (including setting up the server, creating a user and starting the server for the first time can be found at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/windows-installation.html

Looking at the new details on here, you're trying to do 2 things with 1 statement. If you really want to allow root access from everywhere (this comes with security implications, I'd normally recommend root use is restricted to `localhost`), you would use something like `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';` and to change the password you'd use something like `ALTER USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`

Comment: So I tried using ```GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';``` but this time got **ERROR 1410 (42000): You are not allowed to create a user with GRANT**

Comment: By default `root` only has access from `localhost`, looks like you've missed out creating another user for `%` (access from anywhere). I'd recommend naming that user something other than root too, try `CREATE USER 'newuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'user_password';` (replacing the username and password) then `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'newuser'@'%';`

Comment: I'll try that right away but I want to make sure of something first. I'll upload my DB file to the internet where the professor will download then test it via scripts. To make that possible, I must grant a user (in this case the one I'm going to create) access from anywhere, right?

Comment: You need to grant access from where the script is running, so if the script is running locally on their PC they only need access from `localhost`, you could restrict it to IPs or IP ranges or `%` if you don't know (most to least secure)

Comment: Are they, by default, able to access from ```localhost```?

Comment: root is, that's most likely how you're running your commands

Comment: If this solves your issue, please can you mark it as the answer?

Comment: I'm so unfamiliar with the terms and I do not know what root really is. Let me rephrase my question: will other PCs be able to run the DB I will upload or do I need to change something?

Comment: You answered the problem I asked so no worries but I realised my problem was something else: not being sure if I need to do something so that my DB file runs on other computers.

Comment: Thanks! As long as they're running the same version of mysql, you'll probably be fine